# Integration by parts on $\phi(x)\Delta^{2}u$ over $U$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working on the weak form of the Boundary Value Problem given by

$$\Delta^{2}u + \gamma\Delta u = f \text{   in }U$$
$$u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} = 0 \text{   on } \partial U$$

Moving everything to the left side of the strong form and supplying a test function $\phi$ and integrating over U we have

$$\int_{U} \phi(\Delta^{2}u + \gamma\Delta u - f) dx = 0$$

The first tirm $\int_{U} \phi \Delta^{2}u dx$ is where I am stuck; I don't recall ever seeing $\Delta^{2}$ or what that would even look like. I feel like an explanation of what that means and also how to integrate by parts for this particular portion would be very helpful.

Comment: $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator. $\Delta^2$ means apply the Laplace operator twice. So, if you know how integration by parts/divergence theorem works for $\Delta$, then you know (or you should be able to figure it out with some patience) how it works for $\Delta^2$ simply by doing the argument twice.

Comment: @peek-a-boo if my notation is correct, then $\Delta u$ is the divergence of the gradient of $u$ whereas $\Delta^{2}$ would be the divergence of the divergence of the gradient of $u$?

Comment: $\Delta$ is the Laplacian, so yes it’s the divergence of the gradient. Now reread my comment.